# setting values to __proto__` and `prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the difference between `__proto__` and `prototype`

I read most of articles in the web and I still cannot understand it..
as far as I understand 
`__proto__`  is the property which is for prototype object
`prototype` is the actual object
am I correct? ....

Why only functions have prototype property?
And how is it be an object?

```
var fn = function(){};
console.dir(fn);
```

output

> ```
> function fn()
>   arguments: null
>   caller: null
>   length: 0
>   name: ""
>   prototype: Object
>   __proto__: ()
>   <function scope>
> ```

---

Using object and function I try to set values for `__proto__`
and prototype in chrome console as shown below

```
//create object and display it
var o = {name : 'ss'};
console.dir(o);
```

output

> ```
> Object
>       name: "ss",
>       __proto__: Object
> ```

---

```
//set the values
o.__proto__ = 'aaa';
o.prototype = 'bbb';

//after set the values display the object
console.dir(o);
```

output

> ```
>  Object
>       name: "ss",
>       prototype: "aaa",
>       __proto__: Object
> ```

---

```
//create function and display it
var fn = function(){};
console.dir(fn);
```

output

> ```
> function fn()
>   arguments: null
>   caller: null
>   length: 0
>   name: ""
>   prototype: Object
>   __proto__: ()
>   <function scope>
> ```

---

```
//set the values
fn.prototype = 'fff';
fn.__proto__ = 'eee';

//after set the values display the object
console.dir(fn);
```

output

> ```
> function fn()
>   arguments: null
>   caller: null
>   length: 0
>   name: ""
>   prototype: "fff"
>   __proto__: function()
>   <function scope>
> ```

Then I realize that I can't set values for  `__proto__`   but can set values to `prototype` . W why can't I set values for  `__proto__`   ???

Comment: A function's `.prototype` property doesn't affect the function itself, it refers to the object that will become the prototype for objects that are instantiated by calling that function with `new`. An object's `.__proto__` property refers to that object's actual prototype. That is, `Fn.prototype === (new Fn()).__proto__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple actually.

1. `{object}.__proto__` is a reference to `{constructor function}.prototype` object.
2. operator `new {constructor function} (params)` in JavaScript does three major things:

   1. Creates new object, let it be 'obj'.
   2. Calls that `{constructor function}` with `this` set to that newborn object (obj).
   3. Sets `obj.__proto__ = {constructor function}.prototype;`

And that's pretty much it.

That `obj.__proto__` establishes single linked list used to lookup for properties not defined in the object itself. As it is set to `{constructor function}.prototype` object then we can treat that prototype as a "rack" for object methods - functions associated with object instances.

Example:

```
function Foo() {} 
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { return "foo.bar here"; }

var obj = new Foo(); // creating object with __proto__ set to Foo.prototype;

obj.bar(); // will return "foo.bar here"
```

Answer (score 2):

In most languages, there are classes and objects. Classes inherit from other classes.

In JavaScript,

The inheritance is prototype-based. That means that there are no classes. Instead, an object inherits from another object.

**Inheritance, the `__proto__`**

When an object *rabbit* inherits from another object *animal*, in JavaScript that means that there is a special property set `rabbit.__proto__ = animal`.

[image]

When a `rabbit`'s property is accessed, and the interpreter can’t find it in `rabbit`, it follows the `__proto__` link and searches in `animal`.

```
var animal = { eats: true }
var rabbit = { jumps: true }
rabbit.__proto__ = animal  // inherit
alert(rabbit.eats) // => true
```

**The `prototype` property**

When calling the constructor function, `new` operator implicitly sets the `__proto__` property of the newly created object to the value of the constructor's `prototype` property.

```
var animal = { eats: true }
 function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name
}
Rabbit.prototype = animal
var rabbit = new Rabbit('John')
alert( rabbit.eats ) // => true
```

[Complete Reference.](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance)